# Modifying object members inside ArrayList

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am making an ArrayList of Bar Object.  I then want to be able to modify the BarType member contained in the ArrayList.  I created a shortened version of my code that actually is doing what I want it to do, but I do not understand why it is doing it.

In the code I create two Bar objects and stuff them into a ArrayList.  I pull the last Bar Object out of the list cast it to Bar. But TMP is a new instance of the BAR object, yet when I change the value in TMP it changes the values in my arraylist.  I am not sure why it does it or if this is the best way to change the BarType value in an ArrayList.

Below is the code:

```
ArrayList barArray = new ArrayList();

Bar myBar = new Bar(10,20);

barArray.Add(myBar); // I want to create and keep adding Bar object to my arraylist

myBar = new Bar(30, 40);

barArray.Add(myBar);

Bar tmp = new Bar(5,6);
tmp = (Bar)barArray[myBar];  // extracting the last Bar Object
tmp.BarType = true;
tmp.High = 100;              // too my surprise this change the value in the ArrayList
```

So below is my Bar class:

```
public class Bar 
{
    public double High, Low;
    public bool BarType;      // I want to be able to modify this variable

    public Bar(double Low, double High)
    {
        this.Low = Low; this.High = High;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you need to be tortured with using `ArrayList` instead of `List<Bar>`?

Answer (score 2):

> But TMP is a new instance of the BAR object, yet when I change the value in TMP it changes the values in my arraylist

This is incorrect. This would be the case if you were using `struct Bar` or value-types/copy-constructors in C++, but in C#/.NET all `class` objects are heap-allocated and referred to by references, which in turn are passed by-value (which is to say, the references are passed by-value).

To get the copy-on-assignment behaviour you're expecting, change `class Bar` to `struct Bar` (or implement `IClonable` and use `.Clone()` to get the new `Bar` instance).

Here you're creating a new instance of `Bar` on the heap, accessed by the reference named `tmp`

```
Bar tmp = new Bar(5,6);
```

But here, you're overwriting the reference in `tmp` with a new reference to the last item in `barArray`. The *original* `tmp` `Bar` instance has no references pointing to it and will be garbage-collected.

```
tmp = (Bar)barArray[c];
```

`tmp` is now a reference (essentially an alias) to an item in `BarArray`:

```
tmp.BarType = true;
tmp.High = 100;
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
barArray[c].BarType = true;
barArray[c].High = 100;
```

Also, protip: only types (`class`, `struct`, etc) should have `TitleCase` names along with public members (methods, properties, etc). Local variables and parameters should be in `camelCase`. Fields should also either be `camelCase` or `_underscorePrefixed` at your discretion.

Comment: Objects aren't passed at all - references are passed, by value by default. Saying that "class objects are passed by reference" is misleading. (In particular, it suggests that using `ref` for a parameter whose type is a class is pointless - but it's not.) See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @JonSkeet "References are passed by-value" is a confusing concept to beginners though as then we're debating English semantics. By "passing by-reference" I mean "assigned by-reference" or "assignment is only of references" but I struggle to find a way to describe this that isn't re-using words that have deeper meanings, such as "reference".

Comment: Use the words that are accurate then - which is "arguments are passed by value by default, and the value of a reference-type variable is a reference". I've explained this concept to hundreds of beginners over time - and while it takes a little bit more time (ideally with real-world analogies), it's *much* better than leaving people with a confused notion of what pass-by-reference means, in my experience... I've had to clean up the mess of people *being* confused by that. It's not a matter of debating *English* semantics - it's a matter of using well-understood computer science terms properly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've re-worded my explanation.